# Java Pointer vs C# IntPtr

Tags: c#

Hi have to use a dll.
In Java we use this :

```
Public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
    Native.loadLibrary("are32.dll",
    CLibrary.class);
    Pointer ENCRYPT(String a, int ai, String b, int bi);
}

...

Pointer ptr1 = CLibrary.INSTANCE.ENCRYPT("TEST",5,"TEST",5);
for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
  System.out.println((ptr1.getByte(i)& 0xFF));
```

Can you help me to find the equivalent in C# please?
I used IntPtr but I can't find a ReadByte like Java.

```
    [DllImport("are32.dll",)]
    public static extern IntPtr ENCRYPT(string p1, int p2, string p3, int p4);

...

var retPtr = ENCRYPT("TEST", 5, "TEST", 5);
```

How Can I `ReadByte` from `retPtr`? `IntPtr` is it equals to `Pointer`?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

use

```
byte b = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(retPtr);
```

you can also fill your 5-byte array with a single call:

```
const int arrSize = 5;
byte[] arr = new byte[arrSize];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(retPtr, arr, 0, arrSize);
```

Comment: MSDN/Google. A very great combo.